# Serving shared media / content securely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a few MVC4 websites that share some of the same images / videos / pdfs etc. They are confidential: that is only authorized users can access them.
At the moment I just have the content in a folder under one of the web apps, and then I create a symlink to that folder from within the other web apps so that they share that directory. I don't want to do this because it makes things complicated for testing and deployment and would rather have some kind of CDN type of website to serve it.
What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've answered your own question. Try using a CDN instead of having them inside your server(s) and shared across your other web apps. Some CDN's may or may not have authentication.

One CDN you might want to consider:
[Amazon S3 (it has token auth)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_secure_is_my_data)

Another is [Softlayer (this also has auth)](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_ContentDelivery_Authentication_Token)

If you really intend to create a CDN-like website, I would say, do a cost-benefit analysis. Is it worth to build it from scratch? Can you just get a CDN (with authentication, of course) and host it by yourself? Or can you just have it hosted externally (which might be more reliable as well)?

Just my 2 cents.